# Would AC voltage damage the capacitor if using a low voltage rating capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, bias

So I have a circuit below:

- C1 is 6.3V rating electrolytic cap.
- V1 is 6VDC
- V2 is 2VRMS

The DC voltage across C1 cap is 6V and I have 0.3V margin. Since the AC voltage at both terminal of the cap is the same, can I safely say this cap will not damage over it's usable lifespan?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Flfe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 10uF is ~ 1 Ohm @ 1kHz so the voltage drop is minimal with 10k in series.  5% voltage margin is almost nothing but considering the current is always low, it should be reliable if you stick to the above.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick something with more voltage margin, but in a theoretical sense this will work just fine, it is the voltage across the cap that matters, not the voltage between the cap and some external point.

Actually in practise it would probably be fine as well, an electrolytic with a standing DC bias from a highish impedance source is a very robust sort of thing, but you never like to see 6.3V parts in a 6V circuit, just on principle.

Regards, Dan.